# Programmer is not responding error on Arduino when using some custom classes

Tags: arduino, zigbee

I had no problem uploading codes to my arduino for a while, then I found some weird issue. I wrote some code in c++ and imported to arduino sketch.

[image]

When I tried to use C1222_EPSEM class (see picture above), i got programmer not responding error and was not able to upload the code. However, when I commented that class out, I successfully uploaded the code without any problem. I have no clue why this happen. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

it is spamming the serial, then the PC's and USBtoSerial chip's buffers are still full after the reset sent by progroammer PC, then he read a bit of this buffer, it is not the response expected, and voilà.

Please DON'T use image for code